# Zoomed in reputation graph shows incorrect scaling

Tags: bug, reputation-graph

When zooming in on my [reputation graph](https://stackexchange.com/users/404512/false?tab=reputation) the numbers on the side are all wrong. In the concrete case, the blue circle indicates a height of 10,051 but is shown between 9,750 and 9,250.

With FF 52.0.2 I get:
[image]